# C : unknown memory issue ? - Binary Tree exercise

Tags: c, debugging, binary-tree, codeblocks

First post here.

I started learning C using CodeBlocks a few weeks ago, everything has been going smoothly until today, when I encountered this brain-twisting crash issue ; I was able to generate a **binary tree** as a standalone program, but whenever I add up some other functions to use the generated tree, my program crashes and **I'm not even able to understand where is the bug happening**.

I had to reproduce this binary tree below to make a morse translator :

[image: Morse binary tree]

So I made a program called **BinaryTree** first, and it worked perfectly. So I did a copy/paste of the .c and .h files inside a new project file that I called **MorseTranslate**. However, the program couldn't run anymore since I added some lines and functions in the **MorseTranslate.c** source file. So, first reaction, I tried to skip the function call for **morseTranslate(tree)** by putting the "//" before. And for some reason, it still didn't work **AND occasionally, it even accessed the function despite the commented call !** (I remember having seen that many times but I don't remember the conditions to make it happen). And it still shows **no warning** !

I just discovered that I could use a debugger, so I set it up and ran it. Here are the error logs returned from the "where" debugger command :

```
#0  0x00007ff9b52d2477 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from 
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ff9b522e62b in ntdll!EtwEventEnabled () from 
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007ff9b5299a24 in ntdll!memset () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#3  0x00007ff9b526127d in ntdll!RtlCreateHashTableEx () from 
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#4  0x00007ff9b52895c9 in ntdll!memset () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#5  0x00007ff9b52011ed in ntdll!RtlFreeHeap () from 
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#6  0x00007ff9b4f3995c in msvcrt!free () from C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
#7  0x000000000040192f in morseTranslate (tree=0xbe16a0) at 
D:\CodeBlocks\Projects\MorseTranslate_v1\MorseTranslate.c:25
#8  0x0000000000401877 in main () at 
D:\CodeBlocks\Projects\MorseTranslate_v1\main.c:20
```

I've been looking through many posts and forums but I still don't get why my program isn't working anymore. **I'm pretty sure it's either because of the malloc() I used for my tree generation or the free(tree) function**, but I don't know what else I can do since I did the **NULL check** after allocating and also **freed the memory** after the switch/case function in **MorseTranslate.c**. So I'm totally stuck here at this point.

Well anyways, I have to send my code to my teacher within 6 hours so I guess it's already late, but I kinda really wanna understand why this isn't working while the binary tree generation program worked alone... Right now I'm feeling a bit upset since I know how to make the translator but can't even make it because of this weird bug.

Thank you in advance.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "BinaryTree.h"
#include "MorseTranslate.h"

int main(){
    Node *tree;
    int depth = 5;

    binTree(tree, depth);
    morseTranslate(tree);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**BinaryTree.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "BinaryTree.h"

void binTree(Node *tree, int depth){
    char letters[31] = {'\0', 'E', 'T',
                              'I', 'A', 'N', 'M',
                              'S', 'U', 'R', 'W', 'D', 'K', 'G', 'O',
                              'H', 'V', 'F', ' ', 'L', ' ', 'P', 'J',
                              'B', 'X', 'C', 'Y', 'Z', 'Q', ' ', ' '};
    int totalNodes = (pow(2, depth)-1);
    tree = malloc(totalNodes*sizeof(Node));

     if(tree == NULL){        //checker
        printf("OOPS!");
        return 0;
    }

    binTreeGen(totalNodes, totalNodes, tree, letters);
}

void binTreeGen(int i, int totalNodes, Node *tree, char *letters){

    if(i>=totalNodes/2){
        tree[i].data  = letters[i];
        tree[i].right = NULL;
        tree[i].left  = NULL;
    }else{
        tree[i].data  = letters[i];
        tree[i].right = &tree[2*i+2];   //2i+2 right
        tree[i].left  = &tree[2*i+1];   //2i+1 left
    }

    if(i>0)
        binTreeGen(i-1, totalNodes, tree, letters);
}
```

**MorseTranslate.c** (writeMorse() is empty on purpose, haven't written it yet)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "BinaryTree.h"
#include "MorseTranslate.h"

void morseTranslate(Node *tree){
    int selected = 3;

    while(selected>2||selected<0){
        printf("Choose your translation mode :\n1 : READ MORSE\n2 : WRITE MORSE\n0 : LEAVE\n");
        scanf("%d", &selected);

        switch(selected){
            case 1: readMorse(tree);
                    break;
            case 2: writeMorse(tree);
                    break;
            case 0: printf("\nleaving...\n");
                    break;
           default: printf("\nERROR : NOT AVAILABLE !\n");
        }

    }

    free(tree);
}

void readMorse(Node *tree){
    char code[256]     = {'\0'};    //stores morse code
    int  cursor        = 0;         //read cursor for morse code array
    int  morseCursor   = 0;         //index for morse binary tree array
    bool stopRead      = false;     //bool to stop the while loop
    bool isSpace       = false;     //bool to recognize one morse letter

    system("cls");
    printf("Input your morse code with dots '.' and dashes '-'.\nPlease input space between two morse letters.\nDO NOT put spaces between dots and dashes in a same morse letter.\n");
    getchar();
    fgets(code, 256, stdin);
    printf("\n\nTranslation : %s\n\n", code);

    while(!stopRead){

        switch(code[cursor]){
            case '-' :  morseCursor = 2*morseCursor+2;
                        break;
            case '.' :  morseCursor = 2*morseCursor+1;
                        break;
            case ' ' :  isSpace = true;
                        break;
            case '\0':  stopRead = true;
                        break;
            default  :  printf("\nWARNING : SYMBOL No.%d ISNT A DOT '.' NOR A DASH '-' !\n", cursor+1);
        }

        if(isSpace){
            printf("%c", tree[morseCursor].data);
            morseCursor = 0;
            isSpace = false;
        }

        cursor++;
    }

}

void writeMorse(Node *tree){
}
```

**BinaryTree.h**

```
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H_INCLUDED
#define BINARYTREE_H_INCLUDED
#include <math.h>

typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0

typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
    char data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

void binTree(Node *tree, int depth);
void binTreeGen(int i, int totalNodes, Node *tree, char *letters);

#endif // BINARYTREE_H_INCLUDED
```

**MorseTranslate.h**

```
#ifndef MORSETRANSLATE_H_INCLUDED
#define MORSETRANSLATE_H_INCLUDED
#include "BinaryTree.h"

void morseTranslate(Node *tree);
void readMorse(Node *tree);
void writeMorse(Node *tree);

#endif // MORSETRANSLATE_H_INCLUDED
```

Answer (score 1):

The code isn't doing what you think is doing:

First: Debugging tips: why could free fail? Or you are freeing something that wasn't malloc-ed (or friends like strdup, calloc, etc), or the pointer haven't been allocated at all... The first option looks unlikely (only one free in the program...), so suspect on the second one.

```
int main(){
    Node *tree;
    //...

    binTree(tree, depth);
    //...
}

void binTree(Node *tree, int depth){
    // ...
    // here is the error! malloc is stored in local variable
    tree = malloc(totalNodes*sizeof(Node));
    // ...
}
```

Now, the malloc is correct, but it is storing the resulting pointer in a local variable of binTree, not the one in main. In this case, what you want is:

```
int main(){
    Node *tree;
    //...

    binTree(&tree, depth);
    //...
}

void binTree(Node **tree, int depth){
    // ...
    // Now the malloc result is stored in the main's pointer.
    *tree = malloc(totalNodes*sizeof(Node));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Nice job walking through the thought process.

Comment: The code you posted is incorrect.  You are still only assigning to `tree` locally.  There are other memory problems as well that you have not addressed.

Comment: Fixed. @TomKarzes The question was regarding *that* memory issue. Also stackoverflow is not the correct place for a full code review, it is more in line with https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: What are you talking about?  Even with this fix applied (well, the corrected fix), the code will *still* seg fault due to writing beyond the array bounds.  The code review site is for ways to improve *working* code.  The problem I'm describing will cause a seg fault.  And no, the code did not specifically point to "that" memory issue.  As I explained, there are multiple memory *bugs*.  You only saw one.

Comment: In fact, the array bounds issue will be encountered *before* the bug you described, so by your logic, the question was about *that* bug, not yours.

Comment: @TomKarzes, you are free to write your own answer, you know? You are the kind of people that makes others stop helping.

Comment: My original comment was extremely helpful.  I pointed out that your fix didn't work (until you edited it), and I pointed out that you had missed some problems.  I thought you might enjoy searching for what you missed so you could improve your answer.  *You* are the one who decoded to "correct" me by implying that I was somehow offering code review advice.  I was not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer estebarb, I tried your double pointer thingy and adapted the remaining tree calls to a double pointer syntax, but it still says there's a memory error ; although it returns a different error code which is 0xFF. I'll try looking around again to see what I can do.